# Messing around with Aliasing

Tags: python, pointer-aliasing

I have the following code that works as expected:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a

>>> b is a
True
```

if I change it up a little it still works:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a[2] * 2

>>> b is a[2] * 2
True
```

Now the problem:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a * 2

>>> b is a * 2
False
```

Can someone please explain to me why this returns False, while `b is a[2] * 2` returns True?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `a` is a list, `a * 2` creates a new list instance.  If you call `a * 2` twice, you create two new list instances -- that's why `b is a * 2` yields `False`.

The reason that you get `True` for `b is a[2] * 2` is an optimisation of CPython that caches small integers.  Since integers are immutable in Python, it actually does not matter if you get a new instance or a cached one, and for small integers, Python returns a cached version if you hit the same integer again.  Also try

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 300, 4]
>>> b = a[2] * 2
>>> b is a[2] * 2
False
```

Comment: The bottom line of course, is don't use `is` unless you really want [object identity](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) ; use `==` for numerical comparison.

Comment: Great explanation! @Andrew, I definitely see the benefit of using `==` instead of `is`.

Answer (score 2):

Identical lists aren't equivalent when compared `is` unless they reference the same list.  Just because the lists have the same values doesn't mean they reference the same list in memory.

E.g.,

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> id(a) # memory location list a references
161267628
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> id(b) # memory location list b references, a different memory location than list a
161276396
>>> a == b 
True
>>> a is b
False
>>> c = a # by this method of assignment; c points to the same point that a does;
# hence changes to a and changes to c, will change both.
>>> id(c) # memory location that c references; this is the same as where a points.
161267628
>>> a is c
True
>>> c.append(4)
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print c
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d = a[:] # this just copies the values in a to d.  
>>> id(d)
161277036
```

This makes sense that they point to different memory locations, because if you may want to say change the first list (like append `4` to the end `a`) without modifying `b` which wouldn't be possible if `a` and `b` pointed to the same location in memory.

Comment: I like your use of memory locations, as it has helped me to understand what python is actually doing with the assignments. I have a feeling I will use `id()` a lot in the future.

Answer (score 0):

a * 2 constructs a new list, while an integer has identity with itself.

```
>>> type(a[2] * 2)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(a * 2)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Two integers with the same value may not be identical instances -- see the example I gave in my answer.

Comment: This is indeed the case. 2 ** 32 is 2 ** 32 => False.